# MPAndroidChart: Bar Chart variables X entries

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have added `MPAndroidChart` project to my code and I would like to use Bar Chart but for the x-entires I want to enter *start* date and *end* date variables.

Please how can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution but not totaly good:

I have modify the public class DayAxisValueFormatter like below:

```
private BarLineChartBase<?> chart;
private String[] mValues;
private ArrayList<Long> mDateList = new ArrayList<Long>();
private int mSize;

public DayAxisValueFormatter(BarLineChartBase<?> chart, ArrayList<Long> DateList, int size) {
    this.chart = chart;
    this.mDateList = DateList;
    this.mSize = size;
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

    // "value" represents the position of the label on the axis (x or y)
    return longToStringForTimeReal(mDateList.get( mSize));
}

//Pour le formatage de la date

public static String longToStringForTimeReal(long time) {
    Date date = new Date(time);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    return simpleDate.format(date);
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
AxisValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new DayAxisValueFormatter(mChart,mDateList, mDateList.size());
xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);
```

The issue with that method is: We got the same date on X values.